# Creating a Search Function, using stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, search, stored-procedures

Supposedly I have the ProjectCode textbox:

```
<td align="left" width="200px">
  <asp:TextBox ID="TbProjectCode" runat="server" Width="194px"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

and one imagebutton:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="BtnSearch" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Support/Image/MagnifierGlass.png" Width="75%" Height="75%" OnClientClick="openNewWin();return false;" />
```

and a gridview:

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelDGV" runat="server" Height="100%" ScrollBars="None" Width="100%">
  <asp:GridView ID="DGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="2" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
      <Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectCode" HeaderText="Project Code" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectName" HeaderText="Project Name" />
  <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="../Support/Image/Edit.png" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CommandName="CmdSearch" HeaderText="Edit">
  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
       </asp:ButtonField>
          </Columns>
             <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                    </asp:GridView>
                       </asp:Panel>
```

and i"m using a stored procedure with query (i take the value from another database, notice the double dot in Master..[MS_Project]):

```
SELECT [projectCode],[projectName]
  FROM Master..[MS_Project]
  WHERE [projectCode] like '%' + @ProjectCode + '%'
  ORDER BY [projectCode] ASC
```

I want to create a search function, so the user type into the textbox what project code they want, then click the imagebutton, then the search result should be displayed in the gridview, is there anyway to do this? thank you.

**EDIT**

I add in the .vb:

```
    Protected Sub BtnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles BtnSearch.Click
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CfgConnectionString").ToString())
        Using command As New SqlCommand()
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            command.CommandText = "msProject_Select"
            command.Connection = connection

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectCode", TbProjectCode.Text)

            connection.Open()
            Dim a As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
            a.Fill(ds)
        End Using
    End Using

    DGV2.DataSource = ds
    DGV2.DataBind()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: whats the issue u r facing...the markup and the query looks perfect? do u want the .cs code?

Comment: @PraveenNambiar maybe I need the code behind or whatever needed, can you help please? I'm using VB by the way.

Comment: i will give u the .cs code. convert it using conversion tool r atleast you will get an idea.

Comment: thank you, please post it in answer so I can accept it if it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you can do:

```
protected void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) 
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "youProcedureName";
                command.Connection = connection;

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectCode", TbProjectCode.Text);

                connection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                a.Fill(ds);
             }
        }

    DGV.DataSource = ds;
    DGV.DataBind();
}
```

The idea is pretty simple. On your Search(click) event you are rebinding your `GridView` with a new `DataSource` that you retrieved with your new `SELECT` query.

> VB.NET

```
Protected Sub BtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)
Dim ds As New DataSet()

Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("YourConnectionString").ToString())
    Using command As New SqlCommand()
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        command.CommandText = "youProcedureName"
        command.Connection = connection

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectCode", TbProjectCode.Text)

        connection.Open()
        Dim a As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
        a.Fill(ds)
    End Using
End Using

DGV.DataSource = ds
DGV.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Try this `vb` code. I have used conversion tool to get this. Maybe you might require some modifications here.

Following your comment:

Add this line on your page.

```
public string CfgConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CfgConnectionString‌​").ConnectionString;
```

and change your first line like this:

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CfgConnectionString").ToString())
```

Also you are missing

```
Dim ds As New DataSet()
```

Comment: i edited the dataset to my dataset: DsPlaygroundProject and change the connection string to CF.CfgConnectionString, procedure name to msProject_Select, it's still now working

Comment: post the code of what you have done in the question...must be some small mistake somewhere.

Comment: btw, i have a CF.vb that include this code `Public CfgConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CfgConnectionString").ConnectionString` that's why I input `CF.CfgConnectionString` in the connection string

Comment: well i saw the code u posted and it wouldn't work. see my update at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: where do i put the `public string CfgConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CfgConnectionString‌​").ConnectionString;` ? in the aspx page? on in .vb?

Comment: still not working, maybe I forgot to mention that the datagrid is not contain any data, yet. it's there just to show the data taken from the database using the stored-procedure, is there anything else you can do to help? thank you

Comment: surely, post the code what you have done in your question. it has to be small mistake somewhere. u sure have data to search and show...right??

Comment: there, I've edited my post, yes I have, the data is in another database though, that's why I used the double dot in the stored procedure, and I already checked the stored procedure, and it works well

Comment: Its working now! I don't know why, maybe my computer just have to restart to fix it, I still used your code, now I'm trying to use some DataSet for the search, thank you for your help sir :)